# ValidateInput Cross Site Scripting Prevention not working Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cross-site

Validate Input is not working.The form gets submitted and the `success` view is displayed even when the form is posted with html tags
`<b> hello </b>` 
Why is the cross site scripting prevention not working? It should be enabled by default right?

**Razor View**

```
<h4 style="color:purple">
    <b>ID:</b>    @ViewBag.ID <br />
    <b>Name:</b>  @ViewBag.Name <br />   
</h4>
<hr />

@using (Html.BeginForm("register", "Adder", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextArea("comments");
        <input type="submit" />

    </div>
}
```

**Controller Method**

```
[HttpPost]
        public string register(string val)
        {

          //  quickdbEntities1 ent = new quickdbEntities1();
          //  Player p1 = ent.Players.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "name");
          ////  ent.Players.Add(player);
          ////  int res = ent.SaveChanges();


          //  ViewBag.id = player.PlayerId;
          //  ViewBag.Name = p1.Name;
            return ("success");
        }
```

Update:

I have added **DataAnnotation** [Required] and now uses a form like this.Still the form submits

```
@model Vidly.Domain.Player
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section scripts
{

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval" )

}

@using (Html.BeginForm("register", "Adder", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name,new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />

    </div>
}
```

Comment: Please see update.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are accepting the parameter as string and no validation script in view page (as of we can't see if the layout page has the scripts).

Comment: In the register method in controller, take the model as a parameter. Hope this 'll help!